# Make an object available from dependency injection via more than one type

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection, razor-pages

I have the following interface and classes.

```
public interface IWorkingPath
{
    string WorkingFolder { get; }
}

public class WorkingPath : IWorkingPath
{
    public required string WorkingFolder { get; set; }
}

public class AppSettings : WorkingPath
{
    public bool IsStaging { get; set; }
    public bool IsStagingTrackAndTrace { get; set; }
}
```

And then I have the following section in my *appsettings.json*.

```
"AppSettings": {
  "IsStaging": true,
  "IsStagingTrackAndTrace": true,
  "WorkingFolder": "Xxxxx"
},
```

I then make these settings available to dependency injection.

```
AppSettings? appSettings = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<AppSettings>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(appSettings);
```

This works fine, but now I have some classes that are requesting `IWorkingPath` from dependency injection.

Is there any way to make this same `appSettings` instance available for dependency injection as either `AppSettings` or `IWorkingPath`?

Comment: `public required string WorkingFolder { get; set; }` - I think it's unwise for a shared object (i.e. your singleton `WorkingFolder` service implementation) to have a mutable property. If you _must_ use `required` and/or object-initializers then prefer `init` to `set` - though my preference is to use a _real_ constructor.

Comment: Your `AppSettings? appSettings` _must not_ be nullable if you intend to use it as a service implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to make this same `appSettings` instance available for dependency injection as either `AppSettings` or `IWorkingPath`?

Yes, just register it as such:

```
AppSettings appSettings = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<AppSettings>() ?? throw new InvalidOperationException( "Failed to get AppSettings instance" );

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IWorkingPath>( appSettings );
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WorkingPath >( appSettings );
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AppSettings >( appSettings );
```

...but a better solution would be to make the `class WorkingPath` implementation an `internal` (or move it to a scarily-named `namespace`) to avoid consumers requesting a `class` ctor parameter instead of the `IWorkingPath` interface.

Comment: I didn't quite understand that last part. Consumers need to be able to request `IWorkingPath`, and they don't know anything about `AppSettings`. But I have some common functionality in `WorkingPath` that is used across projects.